# Are there any mocking libraries that support the .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, unit-testing, compact-framework, mocking

I was just wondering if anyone has found a mocking library that can be used with the .NET compact framework.

I have tried Moq but it doesn't seem to work, I did a quick Google search but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the .Net CF doesn't support IL emit, or compilation (via CSharpCodeProvider or such). The better mocking frameworks use IL emit, the older ones use CSharpCodeProvider - both of which are not in the CF.

I would venture to say that it is impossible to write a CF mocking framework (unless someone ports Cecil to CF and uses that to create assemblies on the storage card, and then loads those up dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

The [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122198/automated-test-framework-windows-ce) may be of use as well.