# WinCE 5.0 UI-Testing with DATK

Tags: c#, windows-ce, automated-tests, gui-testing

I'm looking for a way to do automated UI-testing on a Windows CE 5.0 device. It seems that the DATK is the tool that I am looking for (see [Automated Test Framework - Windows CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122198/automated-test-framework-windows-ce)).

I'm using VS 2005, the platform specific SDK and the WinCE 5.0 TestKit is installed but it seems that I'm missing something: according to the MSDN help at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa463259.aspx I should use TuxNetSkeletonTests as a starting point, but it's not installed on my machine.

Is there a additional package that must be installed for using the DATK? What assemblies do I need to add to get

```
using Microsoft.MobileDevices.AbstractionLayer.Shell.PocketPC;
```

resolved?